# Android Navigation drawer not responding on selecting navigation items

Tags: java, android, android-layout, import

I am trying to add a grid view with a navigation drawer but my navigation drawer is not responding to touch once it opens. I can't access any items from the onNavigationItemSelected method. I am also using a grid view and the drawer was working earlier. Can you please have a look?

```
public static ViewHolder listViewHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);


        navigationView.bringToFront();
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        List<ItemObject> allItems = getAllItemObject();
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, allItems);
        gridview.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("position",position);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.Profile) {
            Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this,userprofile.class);
            startActivity(I);
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.support) {

        } else if (id == R.id.aboutus) {

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.krashunt.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private List<ItemObject> getAllItemObject(){
        ItemObject itemObject = null;
        List<ItemObject> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new ItemObject("Amazon Echo Dot", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/krashunt-8ebf7.appspot.com/o/imageedit_1_8004680559.png?alt=media&token=8cf09ac9-0f98-46d8-a827-d6748fe8d2c8"));
        items.add(new ItemObject("LeEco Bluetooth Speaker", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/krashunt-8ebf7.appspot.com/o/imageedit_1_7949050176.png?alt=media&token=794bab46-0293-45a0-8b19-298b137ab1ef"));
        items.add(new ItemObject("Samsung Charm Lifestyle Fitness Smart Band", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/krashunt-8ebf7.appspot.com/o/imageedit_1_7185715928.png?alt=media&token=2040a5b8-5955-4634-98e9-a23aefd00fb7"));
        items.add(new ItemObject("Skullcandy Grind On-Ear with Tap Tech", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/krashunt-8ebf7.appspot.com/o/imageedit_1_7440771859.png?alt=media&token=80c52411-47df-4cfb-9119-9675c9afd85d"));
        items.add(new ItemObject("Samsung Gear VR SM-R323 ", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/krashunt-8ebf7.appspot.com/o/imageedit_1_2950042441.png?alt=media&token=e8c3d994-7c15-42da-9820-a26cdfafb688"));


        return items;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder {

        TextView textInListView;
        ImageView imageInListView;

    }

    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater layoutinflater;
        private List<ItemObject> listStorage;
        private Context context;


        public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> customizedListView) {
            this.context = context;
            layoutinflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            listStorage = customizedListView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listStorage.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            if(convertView == null){
                listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_with_text_image, parent, false);
                listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                listViewHolder.imageInListView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridimageView);
                convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
            }else{
                listViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

            }

            listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getContent());


            Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(listStorage.get(position).getImageResource())
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(listViewHolder.imageInListView);
            return convertView;
        }



    }
```

And this is my main.xml file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">



     <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />
```

And this is my content_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    />`
```